# find parent for a json object using jsonpath-ng

Tags: python-3.x, jsonpath-ng

I have a json obj like below. I need to find all the 'Statement's and respective parent. I was able to find the 'Statement's. But, do not know how to extract their respective parent. I am using Python3, jsonpath_ng. Here is my code so far:

```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
from pprint import pprint

       x = {'MasterRole': {'Type': 'AWS::IAM::Role',
          'Properties': {'Path': '/',
           'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': {'Version': '2012-10-17',
            'Statement': [{'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole'],
              'Principal': {'Service': ['ec2.amazonaws.com']},
              'Effect': 'Allow'}]},
           'Policies': [{'PolicyDocument': {'Version': '2012-10-17',
              'Statement': [{'Action': ['s3:AbortMultipartUpload',
                 's3:DeleteObject',
                 's3:PutObjectAcl'],
                'Resource': [{'Fn::Join': ['',
                   ['arn:aws:s3:::', {'Ref': 'ExhibitorS3Bucket'}, '/*']]},
                 {'Fn::Join': ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', {'Ref': 'ExhibitorS3Bucket'}]]}],
                'Effect': 'Allow'},
               {'Action': ['cloudformation:*'],
                'Resource': [{'Ref': 'AWS::StackId'},
                 {'Fn::Join': ['', [{'Ref': 'AWS::StackId'}, '/*']]}],
                'Effect': 'Allow'}]}}]}}}

In [40]: res = [match.value for match in parse('$..Statement').find(x)]

In [41]: pprint(res)
[[{'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole'],
   'Effect': 'Allow',
   'Principal': {'Service': ['ec2.amazonaws.com']}}],
 [{'Action': ['s3:AbortMultipartUpload', 's3:DeleteObject', 's3:PutObjectAcl'],
   'Effect': 'Allow',
   'Resource': [{'Fn::Join': ['',
                              ['arn:aws:s3:::',
                               {'Ref': 'ExhibitorS3Bucket'},
                               '/*']]},
                {'Fn::Join': ['',
                              ['arn:aws:s3:::',
                               {'Ref': 'ExhibitorS3Bucket'}]]}]},
  {'Action': ['cloudformation:*'],
   'Effect': 'Allow',
   'Resource': [{'Ref': 'AWS::StackId'},
                {'Fn::Join': ['', [{'Ref': 'AWS::StackId'}, '/*']]}]}]]

In [42]:
```

Expected parents: 'AssumeRolePolicyDocument' and 'PolicyDocument'. Would appreciate how to fetch the parents. I am unable to understand how to parse stuff from context data. Here is how I can get the 'DatumInContext' (after which, I am lost).

```
In [18]: res = parse('$..Statement').find(x)
In [19]: pprint(res)
[DatumInContext(value=[{'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole'], 'Principal': {'Service': ['ec2.amazonaws.com']}, 'Effect': 'Allow'}], path=Fields('Statement'), context=DatumInContext(value={'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole'], 'Principal': {'Service': ['ec2.amazonaws.com']} ......
```

There are exactly 2 contexts given (as expected) - for each 'Statement'. And, these contexts have rich info, with full paths and so on. But, I do not know how to get the parent name. I do not know how to use the various functions like jsonPath.parent(), jsonPath.parent.find() and there is minimal to zero documentation regarding this.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You could directly use parent keyword in the jsonpath expression

```
res = parse('$..Statement.`parent`').find(x)
```

Hence

```
pprint( { str(m.path) : m.value["Statement"]  for m in res } )
```

gives

```
{'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': [{'Action': ['sts:AssumeRole'],
                               'Effect': 'Allow',
                               'Principal': {'Service': ['ec2.amazonaws.com']}}],
 'PolicyDocument': [{'Action': ['s3:AbortMultipartUpload',
                                's3:DeleteObject',
                                's3:PutObjectAcl'],
                     'Effect': 'Allow',
                     'Resource': [{'Fn::Join': ['',
                                                ['arn:aws:s3:::',
                                                 {'Ref': 'ExhibitorS3Bucket'},
                                                 '/*']]},
                                  {'Fn::Join': ['',
                                                ['arn:aws:s3:::',
                                                 {'Ref': 'ExhibitorS3Bucket'}]]}]},
                    {'Action': ['cloudformation:*'],
                     'Effect': 'Allow',
                     'Resource': [{'Ref': 'AWS::StackId'},
                                  {'Fn::Join': ['',
                                                [{'Ref': 'AWS::StackId'},
                                                 '/*']]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a hacky solution, but it worked for me. I was stuck exactly where you are.
Try this:

```
res = [str(match.context.path) for match in parse('$..Statement').find(x)]
```

Let me try to explain how I arrived at the solution.
If you print the match object itself like you did

```
In [18]: res = parse('$..Statement').find(x)
In [19]: pprint(res)
```

You'll see that it has multiple keys (thinking of it as a json for simplicity), and the key `value` is what you get when you do `match.value`. Now, check there are other keys as well, and `context` is among one of them. If you looks closely at the contents of `context`, you will find that it contains the json of full node on that level (the level where `Statement` is).

Inside the key `context`, you will see another key `path`. And if you do match.context.path, it should dump the parent object.

You are right, documentation is very minimal, hence had to hack my way around it.